# Composer, Laravel and local packages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, autoload

My issue is I have a package which isn't a repository and I am trying to get it to play nice with Laravel and composer. It is still located under the vendor folder, the only issue is that if I simply set:

```
"psr-0": {
        "Test\\Test": "vendor/test/test/src/"
    }
```

This will load the service provider but none of the controllers etc will autoload. What is the correct way to implement a package with larval that does not have it's own repository. Or does this go against the nature of packages and this should simply be structured under the applications controllers.

The package was created by me using workbench but I found i did not really need this as a separate repository but it would still be good to keep it as a package. Therefore the structure is exactly the same as a regular package:

```
vendor
    testvendor
        testpackage
            public
            src
            tests
            .gitignore
            composer.json
            phpunit.xml
```

UPDATE:

As a solution for the time being I am using:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "vendor/package"
    ]
},
```

As an entry in the class map. Looking forward I will probably refactor this into the app folder or create a repository for this package.

Comment: We need more information about this. What is this package? It's just a bunch of files you copy to your vendor or is something stored in a server you can download? Does it have a composer package structure? Who created this package? Can you make it a composer package and store it in house? Could you at least show us the directory structure of this package?

Comment: Why is there a non composer package in the vendor folder??

Comment: Would you recommend moving it to app/vendor or similar? I will update the question now in regards the other things.

Comment: I think you should creat a **workbench** for your package instead of putting it inside the `vendor` folder. Your custom package should formated as [workbench](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#creating-a-package)

Comment: I did initially have it under workbench (whilst developing) but a workbench package should not be used in a production environment was my understanding? If I was to create a package out of it then yes I would move it into workbench whilst developing, if I am missing something here let me know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have some classes that you're calling "package", you're not supposed to add those files to your vendor folder. This folder is managed by composer and at any time you might loose it. Create a subfolder in your application and put those files there.

You have to be sure your PSR-0 autoloading will work for every single file in your folder structure. So, if your root is `vendor/test/test/src/` and your namespace is

```
Test\\Test
```

All your files must be in

```
vendor/test/test/src/Test/Test/ClassFileName.php
```

PSR-4 is easier to deal and understand, this

```
"psr-4": {
    "Test\\Test\\": "vendor/test/test/src/"
}
```

Means that your files would have to be like:

```
vendor/test/test/src/ClassFileName.php
```

Doublecheck your namespaces. It's easy to make mistakes when using namespaces with PSR-0 and remember that

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Must be ran every time you change things in composer.json or create new files. If it's a simple class autoloading, every time you create a file, if it's a PSR-X autoloading, everytime you create or update a namespace in your composer.json file.

If what you have is is really a package you should use Composer: when your package is structured as a composer package (check Laravel's composer.json as an example), the correct way of adding it to your application, if it's not list in Packagist, is via `repositories`.

You can have (non-packagist) packages in a public VCS repository:

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix"
    },

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can have (non-packagist) packages in a protected by password VCS repository (git, bitbucket...):

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can have your packages zipped in your hard drive and load them via the `artifact` repository type:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "artifact",
        "url": "path/to/directory/with/zips/"
    }
],
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I read the docs and the issue is with it not being a repository. My current solution is I add vendor/odeon to the class map and now everything works fine. I'm not 100% this is the correct method to solve my issue everything is functioning properly.

Comment: If you are mixing more than one autoloading method for the same package, it's not ideal. But if you are just using classmaps now, yeah, it will work, it's just that you probably will have to execute `composer dump-autoload` everytime you create a new class.

Comment: I will keep it like this for the time being but going by comments I should either refactor this into the app folder or make this package a repository. I will accept this as the solution as it does explain what is 'the right way'.

Answer (score 7):

Though @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro's answer is really nice, I had problem with installing custom packages locally(which is also stated in the last part of his answer)

Let's assume this is the directory structure of the package we are trying to install:

```
D:/test_pack
    src/
    composer.json
```

If you do not want to upload your custom package (that most likely you have developed, yourself) to online repositories you can use one of the following two methods:

**Method I**

(You have to specify version for your package, otherwise you'll get this error:  The requested package could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.)

1) In composer.json, Add version to your package. your package's json should look something like this:

```
{
"name": "gandalf/test_pack",//This is your package's name
"description": "some desc",
"version": "1.0.0",//This is the version that you have to specify
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "gandalf the grey",
        "email": "fake@yahoo.com"
    }
],
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "~5.4"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Gandalf\\BotPack\\": "src/"
    }
} }
```

2) zip your package(let's assume the zip file is in D:/test_pack/test_packa.zip)

3) In laravel's composer.json add your package name (in our case gandalf/test_pack into require part of json) and add the repository array to the composer.json file and in that array specify the directory in which your package's zip file exists(in our case D:/test_pack) . like this

```
{
    ...,
    "require": {//adding our package name to laravel's composer.json
        ...,
        "gandalf/test_pack": "*"//package's name
    },
    ...,

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "D:/test_pack"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Method II**(My Favorite method, You have to initialize your package directory as git local repository using `git init` and then `git add .` and `git commit -m "your message"`)

1) initialize the package directory as git directory and commit all your changes to the local repository

(let's say `D:/test_pack` is the directory that contains your package(`src/` directory and `composer.json`))

go to `D:/test_pack` directory and run these commands

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "your message for this commit"
```

2) In your packages `composer.json` file add minimum-stability

```
    {
        "name": "gandalf/test_pack",
        "description": "some desc",
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "gandalf the grey",
                "email": "fake@yahoo.com"
            }
        ],
        "minimum-stability": "dev",//setting minimum-stability
        "require": {
               //dependencies that your package needs
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Gandalf\\BotPack\\": "src/"
            }
        }
    }
```

3)In laravel's composer.json file require the "dev-master" of your package

```
{
    ...,
    "require": {
        ...,//some dependencies that laravel needs
        "gandalf/test_pack": "dev-master"//requiring dev-master from repository
    },

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "D:/test_pack"//path of the local repository directory which contains your package
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: for more detail about Package install from Local System (Offline) see this, https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#artifact

Answer (score 1):

To any Laravel project load local packages. which is stored in your machine.

In laravel's (Project) `composer.json` file add

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "YourPackage\\Namespace\\": "./local_Package_path/src"
    }
  },
```

and fire command in Laravel Project directory

> `composer dump-autoload`

#### Optional

If package is still not available in your Project. then 
Register your package's Service Provider.

To register your service provider, you just need to add an entry to the array of service providers in the `config/app.php` file.

```php
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    ...

    YourPackage\Namespace\PackageServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Hope now your package loaded successfully in your laravel project.